# Mongoose: is there a way to implement this function by using a single mongoose update operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on an API call that deletes a user's display picture by seeing weather he has a dp (display picture) or not, a dp is a string (an aws s3 link).

If the user does not have anything in his dp then nothing happens if he has something in his account then the image is deleted and the entry is updated to "".

This is what I tried.

```
router.post('/deleteDP',jwtValid,function (req,res) {
user.findById({'_id': req.decoded.id}, function (err, result) {
    if(err){return res.send("1");} //error
    else if(!result){return res.send("2");} //no user found
    else if(result)
    {
        if(result.dp === "")
        {
          ///send deleted
            res.send("0");
        }else
            {
                // delete function for result.dp
                user.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id':result.id},{$set:{'dp':''}},function (err,result) {
                    if(result){return res.send("0");}
                });
            }
    }
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can do this using a single mongodb operation rather then two I used in the above code ("findByIdAndUpdate" and "findById")?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way:

```
router.post('/deleteDP',jwtValid,function (req,res) {
    user.findOneAndUpdate({$and:[{'_id': req.decoded.id},{db:{$exists:true}}]},{$set:{'dp':''}}, function (err, result) {
    if(!err){
       if(!result){
           return res.send("2")
       }
       res.send("0");
    }
    res.send("1")

    });

});
```

This should work :);

Comment: Hey @vitomadio This would set the `dp:''` always, I wanted to check if the user's dp is '' or not, how do I do this in a single operation?.....Only if it is not '', then I wanted to make it '' .

Comment: I just edit the code, I not a 100% sure it works but could give you an idea. Happy coding.